# $_post Problem (How to pass the value of $_post)

Tags: php

I have the following code which works well.

The code is to display all the data from the database in input text field format. User is able to edit and update the details by clicking the update button at the end of each row to update the specific row.

Instead of clicking the update buttons one by one (if user wants to edit and update more than one row), now I would like to create a hyperlink which will update ALL the data at once.

The problem now is I dunno how to pass the value of $_post to the "update.php" since I already have

```
<form name="form1" action="submitAction.php" method="post">
```

I am not sure is it possible to do so. Or are there any other alternative ways?

```
<html>
<script language="javascript" >
<!-- hide
function submitRequest(id) {
document.forms[id].submit();
}
// end hide -->
</script>

<!-- The Javasript (Onclick) to Remove the Readonly Attribute-->
<script language="JavaScript">
  function removeAlignment(id){
   document.getElementById("ProjectName_"+id).removeAttribute("readonly",0);
   document.getElementById("DeviceType_"+id).removeAttribute("readonly",0);
  }
</script>

<body>
<?php

$counter=1;
//Connecting and Accessing the Database 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("Project", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Project where status='Ongoing'");

?>

<p><h2 align="center">ADC Project Funnel</h2></p>
<table border="1" bordercolor="lavender" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="20" bgcolor="steelblue" height="15" style="font-size: 11" align="center"><b><font face="Arial">No</font></b></td>
    <td width="78" bgcolor="steelblue" height="15" style="font-size: 11" align="center"><b><font face="Arial">Project
      Name</font></b></td>
    <td width="72" bgcolor="steelblue" height="15" style="font-size: 11" align="center"><b><font face="Arial">Device Type</font></b></td>
    <td width="67" bgcolor="steelblue" height="15" style="font-size: 11" align="center"><b><font face="Arial">Status</font></b></td>
    <td width="67" bgcolor="steelblue" height="15" style="font-size: 11" align="center"><b><font face="Arial"></font></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="15" height="15" bgcolor="#AFEEEE"><font face="Arial" size="1.9">Current Project Assignment</font></td>
  </tr>

  <!-- Records from the database (Current Project Assignment) -->
  <?php 
  $i = 0;
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  ?>
    <tr>
    <form name="form1" action="submitAction.php" method="post">
    <td height="5" width="20"  align="center" style="font-size: 13" valign="middle"><?php echo $counter; ?></td>
    <td height="5" width="72" ><input type="text" autocomplete=off readonly="readonly" id="ProjectName_<?php echo $i; ?>" name="ProjectName<?php echo $row['No'];?>" value="<?php echo  $row['ProjectName'];?>" size="20" style="font-size: 10"></font></td>
    <td height="5" width="72" ><input type="text" autocomplete=off readonly="readonly" id="DeviceType_<?php echo $i; ?>" name="DeviceType<?php echo $row['No'];?>" value="<?php echo  $row['DeviceType'];?>" size="15" style="font-size: 10"></font></td>
    <td height="5" width="67" style="font-size: 13">
    <select name="action" onchange="submitRequest(<?php echo $i; ?>);">
    <option value=>Ongoing </option>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['ProjectName'];?>">Complete</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['Flag2'];?>">Future</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['Flag1'];?>">Cancel</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['No'];?>">Update</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['Flag3'];?>">Delete</option>
    </select>                                   
    </td>
    <td height="5" width="64" ><input type="button" style="width:100%" value="Edit" onclick="removeAlignment(<?php echo $i; ?>);"></td>
    </tr>
    </form> 
    <?php 

    ?>

  <?php 
  $i++;
  $counter++;
  }
  ?>   


  <tr>
  <td colspan="16" bgcolor="#AFEEEE"><font face="Arial" size="1.9">Add New Project Assignment</font></td>
  </tr>

   <!-- Add New Records -->
  <tr>
   <form action="project_insert.php" method="post">
     <td width="20" ></td>
     <td width="78" ><input type="text" autocomplete=off name="ProjectName"  size="40" style="font-size: 10"></font></td>
     <td width="72" ><input type="text" autocomplete=off name="DeviceType" size="15" style="font-size: 10"></font>
     <td width="80" style="font-size: 13">
         <select name="Status" style="width:100%">
            <option value=Future>Future</option>
            <option value=Ongoing>Ongoing</option>        
         </select>      
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="Submit" style="width:100%"value="Add">

       </td>
     </form>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>

<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
         <td valign="middle"><a href="http://localhost/Project/update.php">update</a></td>

  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass value in a link to another page ?

Simply use **$_GET[]** like in this example :

```
<a href="update.php?value=1&toto=2">Update all</a>
```

Comment: That is not a smart thing to do. Search engines for example tend to visit *every* url on a page, which will result it to update everything when it visits this page.

Comment: Yes, but in a back office or in a logged page it's not a problem

Comment: It's still a hack, and not where `GET` requests are meant for. It is asking for all sorts of problems. Use `POST` requests for actions that have consequences.

Comment: W3C rules ! ^^ so the solution for his problem could be a form with hidden input ?

Answer (score 0):

Make just one form tag for everything - not an individual form tag for each row.

Next change:

```
<select name="action" onchange="submitRequest(<?php echo $i; ?>);">
```

To:

```
<select name="action[<php echo $i; ?>]" onchange="submitRequest(<?php echo $i; ?>);">
```

(It's better to use the primary key from your database instead of the $i counter, but you don't say what it is.)

Also it has not been necessary to do:

```
<!-- hide
// end hide -->
```

For something like 10 years already, so you should stop including that.